# sum(case) very inefficient in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have this query where both table are less than 1MB.
Still it take a long time. Is it related to hive where you should not use SUM(CASE)?

```
SELECT
a.weeknum,
SUM(CASE WHEN a.payment_action_type = 'chargeback'  THEN b.chargeback_multiplier*a.num_accounts
 WHEN a.payment_action_type = 'refund' THEN b.refund_multiplier*a.num_accounts END)
as  num_reversals
FROM
hipal2_1921596 a
JOIN  vivekkaul_ads_weekly_arrival_curve b
ON b.weeks_elapsed = a.actual_weeks_elapsed  
GROUP BY a.weeknum
```

Comment: How long is a "long time" and what else is going on in your Hadoop cluster?

Comment: Also, what is the time difference between this query and a query without the sum line and just returning `a.weeknum`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got the appropriate indexes?

Try the following though you may need to review if you other indexes that overlap this

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_weeks_elapsed] ON vivekkaul_ads_weekly_arrival_curve(weeks_elapsed)      
INCLUDE (chargeback_multiplier, refund_multiplier)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_hipal2_1921596] ON hipal2_1921596 (actual_weeks_elapsed  )
INCLUDE  (payment_action_type, num_accounts)
```